# PHP Mysql update statement with embedded _POST

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET order_id='".$data['order_id']."',project_ref='".$data['project_ref']."',supp_short_code='".$data['supp_short_code']."',om_part_no='".$data['om_part_no']."',description='".$data['description']."',quantity='".$data['quantity_input']."',cost_of_items='".$data['cost_of_items']."',cost_total='".$data['cost_total_td']."' WHERE order_id = '".$data['order_id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Oddly its set all fields to "2" (the order_id value) i'm trying to create an "edit orders" page but its not going to plan!?

EDIT:

How i send the data to the PHP:

```
$('#submit').live('click',function(){ 

                        var postData = {};
                        postData['data[order_id]'] = $('#order_id').text();
                        $('#items tr').not(':first').each(function(index, value) {
                            var keyPrefix = 'data[' + index + ']';
                            postData[keyPrefix + '[supp_short_code]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.supp_short_code').text();
                            postData[keyPrefix + '[project_ref]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.project_ref').text();
                            postData[keyPrefix + '[om_part_no]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.om_part_no').text();
                            postData[keyPrefix + '[description]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.description').text();
                            postData[keyPrefix + '[quantity_input]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity_input').val();
                            postData[keyPrefix + '[cost_of_items]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_of_items').text();
                            postData[keyPrefix + '[cost_total_td]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_total_td').text();
                        });

                    $.ajax
                        ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "updateorder.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: postData,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function()
                            {
                                alert("Order Updated");
                            }
                        });
                });
```

Complete PHP Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['data']) && is_array($_POST['data'])) {
                    foreach ($_POST['data'] as $row => $data) {
                        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET project_ref='".$data['project_ref']."',supp_short_code='".$data['supp_short_code']."',om_part_no='".$data['om_part_no']."',description='".$data['description']."',quantity='".$data['quantity_input']."',cost_of_items='".$data['cost_of_items']."',cost_total='".$data['cost_total_td']."' WHERE order_id = '".$data['order_id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                    }
                }
                var_dump($data);
```

Comment: 1/ I didn't understand anything to your question, 2/ have a google-look to "sql injection php mysql" and you'll learn how you won't loose your job/internship/project. And Ithink that the problem is when you build your $data array, your request (except the big security hole) doesn't seem wrong.

Comment: What does `var_dump($data)` show?

Comment: how do i see what it says? if i access the page directly, it show NULL as no values have been passed to it?!

Comment: $data is obviously mal-formed.  You mentioned $_POST in your title, but not in the question/code.. where is $data populated and is it safely escaped to prevent injection?  @benhowdle89 show us more code.

Comment: I know everyone keeps mentioning safety, but the only person using this is me so far. So for testing purposes i dont see it as overly essential to guard against sql injection from...myself.

Comment: and from a trojan that do some http request to your server ? I had it once, it was really nice to have an iframe to a chinese website under every customer name ^^

Comment: ouch. i do fully understand the importance of protecting against sql injection, but at the moment it was more important to get it working

Comment: var_dump($data); shows array(7) {
  ["supp_short_code"]=>
  string(6) "Alldos"
  ["project_ref"]=>
  string(1) "b"
  ["om_part_no"]=>
  string(6) "159190"
  ["description"]=>
  string(11) "4AFUSELINKS"
  ["quantity_input"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["cost_of_items"]=>
  string(4) "1.05"
  ["cost_total_td"]=>
  string(4) "2.80"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is unsafe. You should escape any values sent to MySQL, using `mysql_real_escape_string`
2. What does the data look like? Are you sure `$data` contains the right values?
3. What does the generated query look like, before it's sent to MySQL?
4. There's no need to update the `order_id` (thanks, Fosco)